# <Textarea> positioning in <ul> tree view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I make a simple  tree list with some textareas and with expanding and collapsing elements, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Obliterator/wogurs6L/1/

html:

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <li><span class="caret"></span>
        <textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
        <ul class="nested">
            <li>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </li>
            <li><span class="caret"></span>
                <textarea></textarea>
                <ul class="nested">
                    <li>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="caret"></span>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                        <ul class="nested">
                            <li>
                                <textarea></textarea>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <textarea></textarea>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <textarea></textarea>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <textarea></textarea>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
/* Remove default bullets */
ul, #myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the parent ul */
#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the caret/arrow */
.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none; /* Prevent text selection */
}

/* Create the caret/arrow with a unicode, and style it */
.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* Rotate the caret/arrow icon when clicked on (using JavaScript) */
.caret-down::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Hide the nested list */
.nested {
  display: none;
}

/* Show the nested list when the user clicks on the caret/arrow (with JavaScript) */
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

javascript:

```
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
        this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
    });
}
```

It is work fine, but, i need for root strings that textareas take all string space, exept space, taken by pointer. If i set style="width 100%" for textareas, how i done in this example, it's allways push the pointer to top (you can see it it first string in example), but i am need, that textarea take all free string space, but pointer still stay at the left. How can i do that?

Comment: You can use the `calc` CSS operator, with it you can use something like `width: calc(100% - 100px)`, for example if your caret is 100px large. You can read more about it here : https://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1630-la-fonction-calc-en-css.html.

Comment: Thank's, it works.

Comment: I see that you declared the answer below as the right one, you should just know that using `position: absolute` put the caret outside of the DOM flow, so nothing will collide with it anymore. Putting elements next to each other instead of one over another is a way better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this style:

```
<li style="padding-left: 15px;position: relative;">
 <span class="caret"style="position: absolute;left: 0;"></span>
    <textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand you. But u talk about left padding its coming from `<ul>` tag.

You can add to css

```
#myUL ul {padding:0; margin:0;}
#myUL textarea {width:100%;}
```